# Updating a mercurial repo that is already cloned to my machine

Tags: mercurial

I have a mercurial repo on two different VMs and worked on the repo on one of the machines and pushed the changes back to the online repo. Is there a way to update the repo on my second VM without re-cloning the repo?

I tried hg update but that did not work.

EDIT: I figured it out.

- hg pull
- hg update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `hg pull` to pull from the online repo.

Provided this is what you did on the first VM:

```
$ hg ci
$ hg push http://path_to_online_repo
```

This is what you need on the second VM:

```
$ hg pull http://path_to_online_repo
$ hg update
```